# Why controllers is being created 2 times in my AngularJS + RequireJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am creating small application called `puzometr`. It is for educational needs only. I want to create this application using AngularJS. Also, I want to use RequireJS as module system.

I have strange problem. I created my test controller and I got problem: controller initialization fires two times.

Firstly, full code available here on [GitHub](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/puzometr) (wait, don't click me, I will explain everything below).

So, problem is in `myCtrl.js` file. Here is code of this file:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('main.myModule', []);
  module.controller('main.myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log($scope.$id);
    $scope.bob = function () {
    }
  })
});
```

It is included in main/controllers/controllers.js by this:

```
define(['app', 'main/controllers/myCtrl'], function (app) {
  var module = angular.module('main.controllers', ['main.myModule']);
});
```

This file included in main.js by this code:

```
angular.module('main', ['ngRoute', 'main.services', 'main.controllers', 'main.directives']);
```

And main.js is included into app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'main', 'common']);
```

So, I incidentally noticed, that function definition in myCtrl controller fired two times. I put `console.log` there and saw this:

[image]

Can you please explain me why is this happens? Why controller is being initialised two times?

Also, I have this in ng-inspector:

[image]

So one scope is created as child for another scope. Notice, that scope with id `3` has correct controller name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ng-route to register controllers and bind them with views, then don't add them again using attributes in your html files.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 7 minutes". Wait a bit, please :)